# How to implement a parent pointer tree Iterator in Rust?

Tags: rust, tree, iterator

So I'm trying to implement a parent pointer tree in Rust. This would be the node of the tree (with the root node obviously having None as a parent).

```
pub struct Node {
    pub parent: Option<Rc<Node>>,
    pub id: i64,
    pub random_string: String
}
```

I've tried to implement an Iterator, so that I could iterate over all the ancestors of a node, but couldn't get it to work. Also, would it make more sense to have the Iterator return an Rc or a &Node?

On request, my (poor) current try at the problem:

```
pub struct ParentIterator<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a Node> // Can this only be an Rc<Node> instead of &Node?
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ParentIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a Node; // Same question here?

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a Node> {
        self.parent.map(|node| {
            // Found this online, does this make sense?
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problems you ran into, and share the code? This will allow us to help you with your specific problem, rather than just writing the code for you.

Comment: As for you last question, you are going to have a hard time trying to return `&Node`, so you should return `Rc<Node>`.

Comment: Well I've tried so many variations and I don't know which is the closest, so I'm not really sure if that would be helpful? The solution shouldn't take more than 10 LoC anyway. I mainly got confused at &Node, Rc<Node> and &Rc<Node> in combination with the Option<_>, as I'm still learning rust. I'll update the question a bit more.

Comment: Straight solution to your problem: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea65a93283c0408e6108afd563ead1a0). If you haven't already, you should really read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: @Jmb, thanks for your reply, but your iterator never seems to update parent, so this seems to loop forever? Also, is it not possible to have ParentIterator hold an &Node instead of an Rc<Node>? Because in the latter case I'd need an Arc if I'd like to use the tree in a multi-threaded context, even if I would just be reading from the other threads, right?

Comment: You're right, [here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5e9ccda50af4cd0753f3d923f87fbf8c) a version that updates `parent`.

Comment: Here's a [version of the iterator that can be constructred from an `&Node`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=608d12509a841b7be052d0e70855c1b8). The iterator itself still needs to store an `Rc` though. If you want to use `Arc` instead, you need to change the defintion of the `Node` type anyway.